# Need help converting from ASCII to binary

Tags: c

I'm very new to C, so I don't know much about it. Pointers are something I still haven't learned...
I need to show a single character in decimal and binary. In decimals its easy but I can't get it to binary in any way... I get the ASCII number and compare it's module with 2 but it shows a really awkward number... what is wrong with the code?(It's in portuguese 
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.c> //library my professor created to assist his students
#include <string.h>
#define MAXIMO 8

int main( void )
{
  char caracter;
  int aux, resto[MAXIMO], contador, decimal, numero;
  printf( "Digite um UNICO caracter: " );
  caracter = getch();
  numero = caracter;
  decimal = caracter;
  aux = 0;
  do
  {
    if (numero % 2 == 0)
    {
      resto[aux] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      resto[aux] = 1;
    }
    numero = numero / 2;
    aux++;

  }
  while (numero >= '0');
  //system("cls");
  printf( "\n\n%d\n\n", aux );
  printf( "\nCaracter em Binario: " );
  for (contador = aux; contador >= 0; contador--)
  {
    printf( "%d", resto[contador] );
  }
  printf( "\nValor decimal do caracter: %d", decimal );
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

somethings I use like getch(); and return 0; in the end are just so my teacher don't kill me... I don't fully know why it's there but it has to be.

Comment: For starters: `contador = aux` needs to be `contador = aux-1;` as `aux` is one past the last index that was set in the while loop above that.

Comment: `while(numero >= '0');` is also wrong. `'0'` and `0` are different values. You want the latter.

Comment: @kaylum if I use contador = aux-1 it only prints 7 numbers and doesn't fill the last one with a 0, that's why I used aux. I saw this '0' error too, thanks.

Comment: About your last sentence: the `getch();` is there so that if the console output is to a popup window it won't just disappear before you can read any output. The `return 0;` is there because the function type is `int` (although `main` is an exception, it is not mandatory in this case to return a value).

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had some errors in the `while` condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXIMO 8

int main( void )
{
  char caracter;
  int aux, resto[MAXIMO], contador, decimal, numero;
  printf( "Digite um UNICO caracter: " );
  caracter = getchar(); // I used getchar instead of getch()
  numero = caracter;
  decimal = caracter;
  aux = 0;
  do
  {
    if (numero % 2 == 0)
    {
      resto[aux] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      resto[aux] = 1;
    }
    numero = numero / 2;
    aux++;

  }
  while (numero > 0); // > than 0 not >= '0' 
  //system("cls");
  printf( "\n\n%d\n\n", aux );
  printf( "\nCaracter em Binario: " );
  for (contador = aux-1; contador >= 0; contador--) //aux-1
  {
    printf( "%d", resto[contador] );
  }
  printf( "\nValor decimal do caracter: %d", decimal );
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

### N.B.

- '0' and 0 **are differents**
- `>` (greater) and `>=` (greater or equal) have **different** meaning

Comment: I've made some changes to my code in which using 7 instead of aux or aux-1 solves the problem of numbers only showing 7 characters I had before. I used getch because I want only one character leaving no room for user mistakes, if I use any other function it lets the user enter more and I'll have to validate the answer.

Comment: @ViníciusBreda you can use getch() if you want, but is not a function of standard c. It's in a library made for windows os.